# Install automator service via command line

Tags: terminal, command-line, automator, bash

I would like to automate my Mac installation flow for services. The following is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -rf ./tempWorkflows
mkdir tempWorkflows
for filename in ./*.workflow; do
    cp -R "$filename" ./tempWorkflows/"$filename"
done
for filename in ./tempWorkflows/*.workflow; do
    open $filename
done
rm -rf ./tempWorkflows
```

It basically copy all my `*.workflow` and open it. However, for `open $filename`, it prompts and asking for a confirmation:

[image: popup]

Is there a way to add `--no-prompt` or similar flag for the open command?

EDIT:

I am using El Capitan 10.11.3

Comment: It's doable however depending on the version of OS X you're running will have bearing on the implementation of the method.

Comment: Updated Mac OS info. I am using 10.11.3, thanks

Comment: This can be done using either AppleScript or Automator creating an application bundle as this will be necessary to allow the App to control your computer by clicking the Install and Done buttons on the Service Installer dialog box.  Doing an Automator app probably would be easiest, using a Run Shell Script _Action_ and a couple lines of AppleScript _code_ using `osascript` by adding a few lines after the `open $filename` line. If your interested I'll create an answer for it however I do not have OS X 10.11 although this does work in OS X 10.10 it should also work in OS X 10.11. Let me know.

Comment: BTW You should have quotes around `$filename` in `open "$filename"` in case any of your Automator Services `.workflow` files have spaces in the names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If **Automator** is closed then open **Automator** and select **Application** under **Choose a type for your document**, then click the **Choose** button. If it's already open the choose **File** > **New** and select **Application** under **Choose a type for your document**.

Add a **Run Shell Script** *Action* to it.

Copy and paste the *shell code* you presently have into the **Run Shell Script** *Action*.

Add the following lines of *code* after: `open $filename`

```
sleep 1
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to click button "Install" of window "Service Installer" of process "Automator"'
sleep 1
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to click button "Done" of window "Service Installer" of process "Automator"'
```

Note: You should also add an appropriate `cd` line above the `rm -rf ./tempWorkflows` line you presently have in your *code*, e.g. `cd /some/directory/path` where it's the *pathname* of the location your `.workflow` files are located for processing by your *script*.

Save the **Automator Application** as **Install Automator Service**.
[image: Install Automator Service]
**Next:**

Open **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Accessibility** > **Privacy**

Click the **Lock** icon to make changes and type in your password, then click the **Unlock** button.

User the **[+]** to add the **Install Automator Service** or drag and drop the application bundle into the window.
[image: Accessibility]
This will now allow the **Install Automator Service** application to run your *shell code* and use the AppleScript *code* to click the **Install** button and subsequent **Done** button on the **Service Installer** dialog box in the process of installing your *Services*.

Answer (score -1):

When you "Open With..." an Automator Service, the default app to open the file is `Automator Installer.app`.

This app offers to install the Service and moves the file to your system Services directory.

I'm guessing that if you instead open the file with `Automator Runner.app` it will run the Automator workflow and not offer to install the Service.

Change your `open $filename` to instead open the file with a specific application rather than the default.

[image: Open With menu]

Comment: How can the OP "Change your open $filename to instead open the file with a specific application"?